# Where can I find a speech of a priest to encourage people against invasion?

Tags: middle-ages, religion, thirty-years-war

Where can I find an example speech of a Catholic priest to encourage the common people in order to defense their city against the invaders? - mainly for examples from the Thirty Years War era.

Comment: Do you know this exists but just can't track the instance down or are you just hoping that there might be an example?

Comment: There are many cases this happened. I was wondering if it was roughly recorded in some place -like a novel or autobiography of a first eye witness etc.

Comment: Saint Genevieve said to parisian people to take weapons and defend the city against viking (pagan) invasion. Does that count ? It is way before the 30 years war.

Comment: Still gives an idea.. But I am mainly focused on the speech given by a Catholic priest during the Thirty Years War

Comment: There's the famous "[Cry of Dolores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cry_of_Dolores)" by [Father Hidalgo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miguel_Hidalgo_y_Costilla) in Mexico, but that was during the Napoleonic Wars.